# Confused regarding PCA9685 registers

Tags: arduino, datasheet

I'm trying to implement a minimal PCA9685 driver in C using Linux's built-in I2C API, and am reading the datasheet and the [Arduino library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-PWM-Servo-Driver-Library/blob/2b789da2f0a1545c0fa481091b8ef8d4e694fc4c/Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.cpp#L223)'s implementation of setting the PWM values.

I have come across a confusing paragraph in section 7.3.3 in the datasheet, and I'd like some clarification.

> There will be two 12-bit registers per LED output. These registers will be programmed by
> the user. Both registers will hold a value from 0 to 4095. One 12-bit register will hold a
> value for the ON time and the other 12-bit register will hold the value for the OFF time. The
> ON and OFF times are compared with the value of a 12-bit counter that will be running
> continuously from 0000h to 0FFFh (0 to 4095 decimal).

It states that the registers are 12-bit, am I right to assume that it will simply ignore the highest 4 bits?

The method `Adafruit_PWMServoDriver::setPWM` also confuses me, it seems to write the `on` and `off` values to the `LEDn_ON_LOW` and `LEDn_OFF_LOW` registers, [and then the lower 4 bits of the high bytes](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-PWM-Servo-Driver-Library/blob/2b789da2f0a1545c0fa481091b8ef8d4e694fc4c/Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.cpp#L237) somewhere? Could somebody explain the logic behind those 4 lines?

Comment: `am I right to assume that it will simply ignore the highest 4 bits?` ... no ... read the device datasheet to determine if the highest 4 bits are all `don't care`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registers for each channel are consecutive and there are four registers per channel. So they can be written in one 4-byte transaction.

Two registers are for on time and two registers are for off time.

As each register is 8 bits, and the lower address contains the least significant bits, the 8 low bits are written first and then the high 8 bits.

The high value register has 3 unused bits which will be ignored. The PWM values are limited to 12 bits which are the 4 least significant bits.

The remaining bits of the on and off registers are thus always written as zero. These are the full on and full off bits.